# Валидатор на уникальность django

Tags: python, django, url

Моя модель StatcPages имеет url такого типа:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-z0-9_-]+)/$', StaticPageDetailView.as_view(), name='static_page'),
```

На поле slug стоит unique=True, но ведь там выше есть другие статичные урлы, и поле slug может совпасть с ними. Можно ли как-то самому прикрутить валидатор на уникальность, но дополненный кастомными значениями?

Comment: Не совсем ясно при чем тут поле из БД (?). slug - это имя группы, или в данном контексте - имя параметра, который будет передан в функцию. Единственное требование в регулярках - это то, что имя группы должны быть валидным и не повторяться.

Comment: На примере покажу, на данный момент структура такова:

    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^foto-zoopark/', include('gallery.urls')),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-z0-9_-]+)/$', StaticPageDetailView.as_view(), 
name='static_page'),

Slug может меняться через админку и он может совпасть с news например и валидатор ошибки не выдаст, т.к поле будет действительно уникальным.

Comment: Эмм, я давно джангу не пользовал, но мы точно о [urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/urls/) говорим? Если вы боитесь случаев, когда значение параметра slug будет равно news или foto-zoopark, то можно запретить их в регулярке - [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то вот инструкция, которая поможет Вам получить множество слов, которые нельзя использовать в качестве новых slug:

1. Установите django-extensions

   ```
   pip install django-extensions
   ```
2. Используйте код:

   ```
   # encoding: utf-8

   from django.apps import apps
   from django.conf import settings
   from django_extensions.management.commands.show_urls import \
       extract_views_from_urlpatterns, simplify_regex

   def get_words():
       urlconf = __import__(settings.ROOT_URLCONF, {}, {}, [''])
       res = set()
       view_functions = extract_views_from_urlpatterns(urlconf.urlpatterns)
       for (func, regex, url_name) in view_functions:
           res.add(simplify_regex(regex).strip('/').split('/', 1)[0])
       return res

   stop_words = get_words()
   ```
3. Используйте stop_words для валидации.

P.S. См. [show_urls](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/show_urls.py) для уточнения деталей.